# How do I display Relationship results from Low Search?

Tags: relationships, low-search

I have two channels, Products and Businesses.  The Products channel has a relationship field that ties back to the business selling it.  The products are returning successfully on my results page with keyword and categories. Unfortunately when I try and narrow the results for this relationship it does not work.  The results page is displaying all products and not filtering the result.  I know the entry_id from the business is successfully passing through the form once a business is selected too.

The goal of this search filter is to display products related to a business.  For example, if you select "Business Name" it will display the 10 products related to it.

I have tried a number of different parameters and I'm stuck.  Thanks in advance!

**Form Code:**

```
    {exp:low_search:form result_page="shop/search" query="{segment_3}"}
        <input type="search" name="keywords" class="input-search" placeholder="Search Products" />
        <div class="select-dropdown">
            <select name="category[]">
                <option value="">Product Category</option>
                <option value="">--</option>
                {exp:channel:categories category_group="3" style="linear"}
                <option value="{category_id}"{if low_search_category ~ '/\b'.category_id.'\b/'} selected{/if}>{if parent_id != '0'}&nbsp;- {/if}{category_name}</option>
                {/exp:channel:categories}
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="select-dropdown">
            <select name="child:product_seller[]">
                <option value="">Business Name</option>
                <option value="">--</option>
                {exp:channel:entries channel="neighborhood_business" orderby="title" sort="asc" limit="1000" dynamic="no"}
                <option value="{entry_id}">{title}</option>
                {/exp:channel:entries}
            </select>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn-submit" value="Search" />
    {/exp:low_search:form}
```

**Results Code:**

```
{exp:low_search:results query="{segment_3}" collection="shop_product" limit="18" paginate="bottom" paginate_base="shop/search/{segment_3}" keywords:inflect="yes"}
{if no_results}
<div class="searchNoResults">
    <p>Sorry, your search returned no results.</p>
</div>
{/if}
{if count == 1}
<div class="productItems">
{/if}

    <div class="item">
        <a href="{title_permalink='shop/product'}" title="Learn more about {product_title}">
            {if '{product_a_gift_card}' == 'Yes' AND '{product_image1}' == ''}
            <img src="{site_url}assets/img/shop/products/gift_card.png" alt="{title}" />
            {if:else}
            <img src="{product_image1:thumb}" alt="{title}" />
            {/if}
        </a>
        <div class="content">
            <p class="price">${product_price}</p>
            <h2><a href="{title_permalink='shop/product'}" title="Learn more about {product_title}">{product_title}</a></h2>
            <p class="business">By: {product_seller}{product_seller:title}{/product_seller}</p>
            <a href="{title_permalink='shop/product'}" class="cta-btn" title="Learn more about {product_title}">Learn More</a>
        </div>
    </div>

{if count == total_results}
</div>
{paginate}
<div class="paginationContainer">
    <p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages}</p>
    <div class="paginationLinks">{pagination_links}</div>
</div>
{/paginate}
{/if}
{/exp:low_search:results}
```

Comment: Okay, so, the `product_seller` is present in the Products channel, correct? Can you enable the template debugger and copy/paste all lines that mention Low Search here in your question? That will help to give insight as to what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

This was due to global setting being disabled.  Filters can be enabled/disabled within the plugin's settings.  One checkbox later and it works!  Thanks for the fast support Low.